# How to click on a link on a webpage via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing VBA code to click on a "export" link on a website which appears like this:

```
<a title="Excel" style="padding: 3px 8px 3px 32px; color: rgb(51, 102, 204); font-family: Arial; font-size: 9pt; text-decoration: none; display: block; white-space: nowrap;" onclick="$find('ReportViewer1').exportReport('EXCELOPENXML');" href="javascript:void(0)" alt="Excel">Excel</a>
```

I have seen a lot of similar threads but they are not working for me. Following is my current code. It searches for today's date and opens the website if some particular values are missing.

```
Sub FindDate()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim objElement As Object
Dim ObjCollection As Object
Dim i As Long


Dim hTable As Object
Dim myIE As New Application


'Set IE = CreateObject("INTERNETEXPLORER.APPLICATION")

For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.Range("c1:C269")
    If Cell.Value = [Today()] Then
    Cell.Select
    End If
Next

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Select

If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
    IE.Navigate "https://xyz.de/Reporting?NavigationId=163&ReportDateId=20210908&StartDateId=20210908&BankstructureIds=117324,117326&IncludeIte=true"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
    
    
 
Set Link = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each k In Link
  If k.innerText = "Excel" Then
  k.Click
  Exit For
  End If
  Next k
    
    Else
        MsgBox "Values for today are already filled"
    End If
End Sub
```

I get an error in this line:

```
Set Link = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
```

The error reads as 'Run-time error '462': The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable.'

Comment: Try to find something here:
http://www.mkrgeo-blog.com/launching-google-maps-from-excel-with-the-chrome-browser/

Comment: I tried to find a solution there but unfortunately it wouldn't work in this case.